# Android layout design not the same when app is running

Tags: android, layout

The design of my layout is not the same in Android Studio preview and in the running app :

Design in running app

[image]

Expected design

[image]

Here's the XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:text="Manage messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_messages"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_message"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="Manage activities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_activities"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_activities"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Do you have an idea of what's happening ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `android:layout_width="0dp"` for both Button

Comment: is that image size is same for both

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I guess so, I created them from Android Clipart, they're in the mimap package 5 times in different sizes.

I edited the layout_width for both buttons, didn't change anything

Comment: Why is "Manage messages" height wrap_content not match_parent?

Comment: it wont change.Because the image size different for both.Can you please check its ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="Manage messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bt_messages"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_message"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:text="Manage activities"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/bt_activities"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_activities"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use  `android:weightSum`  in place of 
 `android:layout_weight`  for your inner  `LinearLayout` 

Also you should add `android:layout_width="0dp"` for the children while using `weightSum`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:text="Manage messages"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_messages"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_message"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:text="Manage activities"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_activities"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_activities"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:text="Manage messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_messages"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_message"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />

        <Button
            android:text="Manage activities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bt_activities"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_activities"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```